# Is the verb "describe " intransitive?

Tags: relative-clauses, transitivity

Given the text below:

> Erik believes that personality development is a series of turning points, which he **described** in terms of the tension between desirable qualities and dangers.

I am confused about the usage of the verb "describe". In other words, which of the following sentences is correct?

1. > which he described **it** in terms of ...
2. > which he described in terms of ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first sentence of your two examples is incorrect.

The verb *describe* is definitely a **transitive verb** and in your sentence it has a direct object: *which*.

> Erik believes *that personality development is a series of turning points*, **which** he **described** in terms of the tension between desirable qualities and dangers.

In your sentence, *which* is a relative pronoun linking its subclause to the main clause and referring tot he phrase *that personality development is a series of turning points*. Within the subclause, it acts as a **direct object**. This is also the reason you **cannot** place an *it* in the subclause, because you already have a direct object. If you split the sentences into two main clauses and leave out the *which*, you can use *it*.

Answer (score 2):

The antecedent of "which" is the noun "development". The noun could be repeated:

**Erik believes that personality development is a series of turning points, which *development* he described in terms of the tension between desirable qualities and dangers.**

In fact, in older texts, especially legal texts, you will see the noun repeated, and sometimes the word "said" instead of "which":

**Licensee shall pay Licensor a fee of $10,000, *said* fee to be tendered in four equal quarterly installments.**

Answer (score 1):

Describe is a [transitive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/describe) verb. In your sentence, *which* is the object of the verb, so

2. > which he described in terms of ...

is correct.